# Android: Gradle build keeps pulling down latest NDK version, not using the one already installed

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

I am running a gradle build using `./gradlew build` on a Linux server and gradle keeps trying to install the latest version of NDK (22)

```
Welcome to Gradle 5.1.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Control which dependencies can be retrieved from which repositories
 - Production-ready configuration avoidance APIs

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :ui_manager_library
Checking the license for package NDK in /usr/local/android-sdk/licenses
License for package NDK accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (revision: 22.0.7026061)".
"Install NDK (revision: 22.0.7026061)" ready.
Installing NDK in /usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-bundle
"Install NDK (revision: 22.0.7026061)" complete.
"Install NDK (revision: 22.0.7026061)" finished.
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to /usr/local/android-sdk/ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The server already has NDK installed and the path is set. We need to use **20.0.5594570***

```
ANDROID_NDK_HOME='/usr/local/android-sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570'
```

How can I make Gradle see this? My app/build.gradle also has the version set

```
android {
    ndkVersion '20.0.5594570'
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-agp-ndk#agp_version_41

Comment: That was it. Once we adjusted the agp version, gradle started using the ndk version we wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by WS Ayan, updating the Android Gradle Plugin to the appropriate version allowed us to enforce the NDK version.